# C# MySQL script taking ages to load. Any idea what might be causing it?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I'm making a program that among other things, restores a .sql file into a specified database.
Everything works, the thing is that it take ages to run the script... Any idea why? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
    public void ExecuteScript(string connectionString, string filePath)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new(connectionString);

        try
        {
            MySqlScript restore = new(conn, File.ReadAllText(txtEditor.Text));
            restore.Execute();
            RestoringText.Text = "Restored successfuly!";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No valid SQL file was selected.", ex.Message);
            txtEditor.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Why do scripts usually take long times to run? Usually because the queries are performing poorly (i.e. unoptimized). Run the script in your mysql workbench and see if the execution time is different. That way you can pinpoint the problem more accurately.

Comment: I did that though, and it runs it much faster. I'm using navicat, and the drag and drop of the file takes a couple seconds to mount. Is there something i need to optimise in my code?

Comment: Anything relevant would be in the implementation of `MySqlScript` which is not shown.

Comment: You mean the queries that are being run from the file?

Comment: How slow is slow? If what you're saying about your script running fine on the DB, then you've got two other 'slow' operations here, which is opening the connection, and reading the file. Reading the file is inbuilt and assuming there are no issues there, perhaps there are issues trying to get the connection?

Comment: What I mean is that the code in `Execute` is unknown so we can't even guess what the issue could be assuming it is a problem with your c# code. As mentioned it could also be slow to open a connection or read the file or all of the above. Using the debugger, what line of code is taking all of the time?

Comment: The code in the execute is a ReadAllText in the selected file and execute all the queries inside. Something that takes in navicat or workbench 3 seconds to do, in the program it takes around 3 to 4x more. Its not an issue for small DBs but if its a bigger one, 3 to 4x longer becomes a bit of a headache...

Comment: Is this code being run within a loop?

Comment: Nope. Its just a normal script of INSERT DELETE

Comment: The only thing it comes to mind is that it has a lot of comments in between the queries. Could this be the issue? And if so, is it possible to ignore them?